# Curl requests gets expired after a while when using via Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to access the page but it then starts giving JS not enabled after a while. The actual request dump is given below. I am not being able to figure out whether it is Cookie or something else that is expiring the requests:

```
curl 'https://nsubooks.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/BNCBTBListView' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Origin: https://nsubooks.bncollege.com' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Referer: https://nsubooks.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TBWizardView?catalogId=10001&langId=-1&storeId=10055' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ur;q=0.8' -H 'Cookie: flashMessage=10055:true,; BIGipServerBNCollege_WEBZ_http81_pool=892745482.20736.0000; TS01beedce=013589168b02bad74c7e8973b6b4623f190e5d7f2172f57df98c457e41ef4f1c9cafa08b075fb222e8c7ce25a91638a4dc043b3df3; WC_SESSION_ESTABLISHED=true; WC_ACTIVEPOINTER=-1%2C10055; CoreID6=07894780431415325132648&ci=90222933; __utmc=168970354; __utmz=168970354.1532513266.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmv=168970354.store_298; _msuuid_518wse26072=90F53D32-9E1A-4A66-B803-CA5EB6FFF428; cmTPSet=Y; WC_AUTHENTICATION_372694591=372694591%2CgNnva2inP3A4g3x%2F6jOlOwgKU9U%3D; TS01971484=013589168b8a201be0d8f85b91ff218417abd286abe1c3dc9917ad1c97cc149534bce907b0212beb8ee6f854fa833d39173ceffacf4d8666597a6f4fe91ce5821c80d84141a013a40bc29c8086baaeadf5ace4906e80b7a79af4c3477a592dad1ef31ee554d750584ddb431356ec23b96085a99a3c94b5b2debfdebd87db910082bbe93fba; TS014d5a24=013589168b4f1404886668aa6dd793833ec278e95f44a851dca058eb6068291aa7ff6e5a9e; JSESSIONID=0000owJ9C_-Ya6_E7iasrEKv_FP:prod-appz23; __utma=168970354.895773537.1532513266.1532513266.1533101943.2; __utmt=1; WC_USERACTIVITY_372694591=372694591%2C10055%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C1532513269822%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2COaGBzj8fbAtbin6YqD%2Fo49Sxe41RMPDlmaOwcV0B3vk%2F6fMKiotiL1c7knw%2F6eStmdzA9dRLvzPyQQbbacCwx23%2F63SvQ0JVg34fWM1iI%2Fsr0elu1vihwxK3Xf3ppRppzUDvd4onaDGc9maFQAPnZ6hWobqZL%2BFcDYi6mB%2F6UuVwwiZdaT2g7TpW%2FxlzaJtu%2BlmS9ylS0wDd3l%2FGuUF4RspJsbc9DxIPj0C3a08lDpw%3D; TS01825e4a=013589168b0b64e48e59e7e89aa085c7e90a417747807b2bbf5d0cab91df164abc7f3da9873547196443c642a3f9d16fa0286d3bfd2e93bf55d25453653f7ff300e8cfadc539089af9d5ed465656811f34fba7a8c4e218ef7b231d78afb730f723e167728aa5b99c2d622ea033c2bd0dbdae2378643d1d2dd505900943afbf16c8d72776d908369272ee0659cc1ccead02b1d14bc0; TS015810ea=013589168b4dca5f671fe452e06d0ea932a6b575d14b92b32e1940345be15e570f80209d6c; TS015810ea_1=01e8fc688d97494054bbb70c21ca073d06bcdbe3a89133b3fa2948445ee99e903e92b7ff74399c9b964f78b5d63f3a2baabc583d7f; __utmb=168970354.8.10.1533101943; TS015810ea_77=088fa87ca9ab280022326b1381518c4427c917867e76fb38769003191bc7d77dcb03e196addaa5dc36bf454044e0ec04082e991267823800c88a5e773f72f8888d344138546091179143b362e3d48cad6d2401b0ab35e6ff30a868ce8d54fd86afd47bf17e490edeec8d96a1d0716d10; TS015810ea_30=01e8fc688d18a924a6175cfa8dd6312668ad9bd464eeee2d49d2803482200ff425df8cf9ccda66af65feb66108ed210c6db8b2384c; 90222933_clogin=l=1533101943&v=1&e=1533103908848' --data 'storeId=10055&catalogId=10001&langId=-1&clearAll=&viewName=TBWizardView&secCatList=&removeSectionId=&mcEnabled=N&showCampus=false&selectTerm=Select+Term&selectDepartment=Select+Department&selectSection=Select+Section&selectCourse=Select+Course&campus1=10000004&firstTermName_10000004=UNIVERSITY+SCHOOL&firstTermId_10000004=86746016&section_1=86546801&section_2=&section_3=&section_4=&numberOfCourseAlready=4' --compressed
```

Comment: How long is "a while?" Some servers close HTTP requests that persist for too long.

Comment: @phalt within 5 mins.

Comment: Yeah I think that's your problem. Most HTTP connections will close after 60 seconds.

Comment: @phalt so how to deal with it? I mean, I am just using same CURL and it stops working. Which header is controlling it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `requests.Session()`, it automatically add `keep-alive` -> `true` as a header